# Do upvotes on comments help me in any way apart from badges

Tags: discussion, comments, up-votes

I can understand their unique contribution, but from a reputation point of view, does it help me in any other way (other than badges)? Does Stack Exchange take upvotes on comments into account somehow?

Comment: Nope. It's merely a method of moving the relevant comments to the top when the comment thread gets too long.